# what's the difference between str.split("list, ' ' ") and str.split(list, ' ')

Tags: python, string, list, split

I'm not quite sure the difference between `str.split("list, ' ' ")` and `str.split(list, ' ')`.

When I try to edit the codes given by Learn Python The Hard Way -->

1) Blocks with `str.split(list, ' ')` #The right one I thought.

```
ten_things = "Apples Oranges Crows Telephone Light Sugar"
stuff = str.split(ten_things, ' ')  
more_stuff = ["Day", "Night", "Song", "Frisbee", "Corn", "Banana", "Girl", "Boy"]
print "Let's check our list now. \n%s" % ten_things
while len(stuff) != 10:
    next_one = more_stuff.pop()
    print "Adding: ", next_one
    stuff.append(next_one)
    print "So there's %d items now." % len(stuff)

print "There we go: ", stuff
```

and the result --->

```
Wait there's not 10 things in that list, let's fix that.
Let's check our list now.
Apples Oranges Crows Telephone Light Sugar
Adding:  Boy
So there's 7 items now.
Adding:  Girl
So there's 8 items now.
Adding:  Banana
So there's 9 items now.
Adding:  Corn
So there's 10 items now.
There we go:  ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Crows', 'Telephone', 'Light', 'Sugar', 'Boy', 'Girl', 'Banana', 'Corn']
```

2) Blocks with `str.split("list, ' ' ")` #There may be something wrong with it.

```
ten_things = "Apples Oranges Crows Telephone Light Sugar"
stuff = str.split("ten_things, ' '")    
more_stuff = ["Day", "Night", "Song", "Frisbee", "Corn", "Banana", "Girl", "Boy"]
print "Let's check our list now. \n%s" % ten_things
while len(stuff) != 10:
    next_one = more_stuff.pop()
    print "Adding: ", next_one
    stuff.append(next_one)
    print "So there's %d items now." % len(stuff)
```

and I got --->

```
Wait there's not 10 things in that list, let's fix that.
Let's check our list now.
Apples Oranges Crows Telephone Light Sugar
Adding:  Boy
So there's 4 items now. #why add from 4th item?
Adding:  Girl
So there's 5 items now.
Adding:  Banana
So there's 6 items now.
Adding:  Corn
So there's 7 items now.
Adding:  Frisbee
So there's 8 items now.
Adding:  Song
So there's 9 items now.
Adding:  Night
So there's 10 items now.
There we go:  ['ten_things,', "'", "'", 'Boy', 'Girl', 'Banana', 'Corn', 'Frisbee', 'Song', 'Night']
```

There are 6 items in ten_things but in line 5 of 2)_Result, why python added item from the 4th one? Also not quite understand the list printed in the last line. 
Could you please tell me the reason of these error?
Thank you very much!

Comment: You're using the exact same code in both of your examples - is there meant to be a difference?

Comment: Your second example is splitting the string literal `list, ' ' ` by the default split character, which is all whitespace.  You can also split strings like you would call any other object method.  In that case, your first call is `ten_things.split(' ')` and your second is `"list, ' ' ".split()`

Comment: Actually, I'm new here. Thanks a lot for reminding me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have this code:

```
ten_things = "Apples Oranges Crows Telephone Light Sugar"
stuff = str.split(ten_things, ' ')
```

then `stuff` will be `['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Crows', 'Telephone', 'Light', 'Sugar', 'Boy', 'Girl', 'Banana', 'Corn']` just as you would expect.

But when you run:

```
ten_things = "Apples Oranges Crows Telephone Light Sugar"
stuff = str.split("ten_things, ' '")
```

**Then you are not using `ten_things` at all, you might as well write only the second line!**

You are only splitting the string `"ten_things, ' '"` by whitespace and will end up with `stuff` being `['ten_things,', "'", "'"]`.

Comment: Got it! It just end up with stuff being ['ten_things,', "'", "'"], and that's the reason why Python start adding from the 4th one! Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Python's `split()` function splits by default as follows:

> If sep is not specified or is None, a different splitting algorithm is applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single separator, and the result will contain no empty strings at the start or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace.

So, if you do not supply a parameter, the default is called.

In your code you call `str.split()`, which is the `str` class' method - this requires a string first (an instance of the `str` object) to work. That's why you pass 2 parameters.

So to answer, the difference is this:

```
l = "sfrsfs"
str.split(l, '')  # l is the string instance you'd like to split, '' the separator
```

However, if you call this:

```
str.split("list, ''")
```

you call the`split()` method on the string `"list, ''"`, and `split()` defaults to its default separator.

Also, realize that `str.split(my_string, '')` is the same as `my_string.split('')`.